# dpylr - mutate with seq_along memory issues large dataset

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I'm using dplyr to manipulate a dataframe which worked fine with the smaller test set I used. With the big full dataset (845986 obs for 6 variables) I'm unfortunately running out of memory on a machine with 16 GBs of RAM.

The relevant part of the dataframe:

```
> head(df)
   V2   name
 1  1   A_185
 2  8   A_185
 3 17   A_185
 4 25   A_185
 5 33   A_185
 6  1   A_123
 7  5   A_123
 8 13   A_123
 9 23   A_123
```

I'm creating a new column id2 which should contain a continous sequence based of the V2 column and dependant on the name column e.g for a different name the sequence has to start anew.

The result should be:

```
> head(df)
  V2   name   id2
1  1   A_185  1
2  8   A_185  2
3 17   A_185  3
4 25   A_185  4
5 33   A_185  5
6  1   A_123  1
7  5   A_123  2 
8 13   A_123  3
9 23   A_123  4
```

The code I was using is:

```
df<-ddply(df, .(name), mutate, id2 = seq_along(V2))
```

I have tried the `.parallel=TRUE` option but still to no avail. I can observe the R process in the task manager at 12% CPU (I have 8 cores) and the RAM is rising to 12 GB and then Linux kills the process (R session aborted in RStudio)

An obvious solution is to split the dataframe into a separate chunks of 60-80k entries and process them separately but maybe there is a solution for doing it all in one go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `row_number()` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(name) %>%
   mutate(id2 = row_number())
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups: name [2]
#     V2 name    id2
#  <int> <chr> <int>
#1     1 A_185     1
#2     8 A_185     2
#3    17 A_185     3
#4    25 A_185     4
#5    33 A_185     5
#6     1 A_123     1
#7     5 A_123     2
#8    13 A_123     3
#9    23 A_123     4
```

---

Or make it more faster with `:=` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, id2 := seq_len(.N), by = name]
```